How do I find the BD_ADDR of a client connected to an ESP32 server using the BLE (Bluetooth Low Energy) protocol?
I am working on a door lock project that can recognize a key by matching the Bluetooth Device Address on the user's phone. How can the ESP32, acting as a server, read the BD_ADDR of a connected client?
please help me anyone :')
I have tried code like this:
class MyServerCallbacks: public BLEServerCallbacks {
    void onConnect(BLEServer* pServer, esp_ble_gatts_cb_param_t *param) {
      Serial.println("Device connected");
      BLEAddress connectedDeviceAddress = BLEAddress(param->connect.remote_bda);
      Serial.print("Connected device address: ");
      Serial.println(connectedDeviceAddress.toString().c_str());
    };

    void onDisconnect(BLEServer* pServer) {
      Serial.println("Device disconnected");
      pServer->getAdvertising()->start();
      Serial.println("Advertising restarted");
    }
};

However, the data displayed or output is different from the actual BD_ADDR of the connected Bluetooth client device. For example, the device address of the connected phone is A, but the data displayed on the ESP32 serial monityour textor is B, and sometimes C, so it's inconsistent. This is the issue I'm facing. To anyone who is an expert in Bluetooth Low Energy, please help.
Thank you

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Today, most devices use a random address for privacy reasons. Since it is easy to spoof a specific BD_ADDR, your idea also sounds terrible in the context of security.
